# How to split string with several char

Tags: javascript, regex

How to split string with several char

i have to split a scope when there are spaces, comma, dash, etc..( ponctuation) and when words are concatenated ( without a space between variable)

For exemple

```
testOne="{{test.test}}  {{test.test}}{{test.test}}";
```

The expected output is

```
"test.test  test.testtest.test"
```

(There are two comma between the first and the second text.text)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Did you try by yourself at least once...????

Comment: i have to read the variable into this example but when it's concatenated or there are ponctuation.. i tried var mySplitResult = testOne.split(/[\s,]+/); OR  var mySplitResult = testOne.split('&nbsp;',',','.',';',':'); but it doesn't work

Comment: your output just shows you replacing the `{` and `}` characters, what does this have to do with split

Comment: In your comment in thefoutheye's answer you say you want to change the text between `{{}}`, change it to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression to get the result what you wanted.

```
testOne = "{{test.test}}  {{test.test}}{{test.test}}";
console.log(testOne.match(/{{.*?}}/g).map(function(item) {
    return item.replace(/[{}]/g, "");
}));
# [ 'test.test', 'test.test', 'test.test' ]
```

Comment: Yes but i don't want to get an array un want to change the text who is between the {{}}

Comment: @user3510152, you did not ask for that you asked how to split them. Reedit your question to ask for what you want.

Comment: yes but i have to first split the string and this is where have errors

Comment: @user3510152 When you split strings, you will get more than one string, right? How will you represent them? An array? That is what, this piece of code does.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired output with a simple `replace`

```
testOne.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, '$1');
// "test.test  test.testtest.test"
```

Remember to set this back to `testOne` if you want it kept as that variable